# How to create a correlation matrix in a dataset with multiple datatypes?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, correlation, python, dataset

I am stuck in a peculiar problem where I need to know the correlation between attributes. So far it has been easier, where all of my input attributes used to be only numeric, and hence without any hesitance, I used to generate a Pearson coefficient based correlation matrix. But now I am working with a business stakeholder, and they have provided me a data that has:

2 Discrete numeric attributes

2 Ordinal attributes (non-dichotomous)

5 Nominal attributes (dichotomous)

[image]

Following are the datatypes:

**Attribute 1:** Numeric (skewed)

**Attribute 2:** Numeric (skewed)

**Attribute 3:** Ordinal

**Attribute 4:** Ordinal

**Attribute 5:** Nominal (dichotomous)

**Attribute 6:** Nominal (dichotomous)

**Attribute 7:** Nominal (dichotomous)

**Attribute 8:** Nominal (dichotomous)

**Attribute 9:** Nominal (dichotomous)

I googled and found that for different kind of pairs, I need to have a different method and thus a different scale each time, to judge whether a pair of attributes are correlated or not.

**Numeric and Numeric**: Pearson method

**Numeric (skewed) and Numeric (skewed or normal)**: Spearman method

**Ordinal and Numeric (skewed or normal)**: Spearman method

**Ordinal (non-dichotomous) and Ordinal (non-dichotomous)**: ?? (I am not able to figure out this one)

**Ordinal and Nominal (dichotomous)**: Chi-square based Cramer's V method

**Nominal (dichotomous) and Nominal (dichotomous)**: Chi-square based Cramer's V method

**Nominal (dichotomous) and Numeric**: Logistic/ANOVA/Point-Biserial

At the end of the day, I wanted to produce something like this, where I can easily explain which attributes (categorical or numerical) is correlated with others, in just one place.

[image]

Any correction, best-practice, comment or suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: Hi - Just waiting for any direction/guidance even if it doesn't qualify for an answer. Otherwise I am thinking of doing pairwise calculations in Python and building a matrix manually in excel for the client.